# Authorization Token getting sent as null in the Response in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-httpclient

I am trying to work with REST API's provided within my Enterprise Application and Angular. What I am trying to achieve is to fetch some data from my Enterprise Application. For this I have to do two things:

1- Login to my Enterprise Application via Angular. For doing so, there's already a custom authentication REST API provided by the Enterprise Application. I am consuming the same. An authentication token is generated which I am saving within localStorage.

2- Send a GET request to the Enterprise Application to fetch data after Authentication happened. This is where I am facing issues. I am unable to pass the authentication token within the GET Request. On Checking the same under "Application" Tab of Chrome Dev Tools, I Could see under "Request Headers" Section that Authorization value is null. Below is the screenshot of the same:

[image]

Below is my code that I have developed:

1 - Authentication Service (auth.service.ts)

```
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
     import{Http} from '@angular/http'
     import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
     import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
     import { URLSearchParams,Response } from '@angular/http'

     @Injectable()
     export class AuthenticationService {
     constructor(private http: Http) { }
     username:string = 'Admin';
     password:string='livelink';  
     token:any; 
     login() 
     {

    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('Username', this.username);
    urlSearchParams.append('Password', this.password);
     this.http.post('http://localhost/otcs/cs.exe/api/v1/auth',urlSearchParams)
        .subscribe((res:Response) => 
        {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (res) {
                const data = res.json();
                ;
                this.token = data;
                console.log(data);
                // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({  ticket: data }));

            }
        });

        console.log("INSIDE LOGIN this.token  = "+this.token)//done for debugging, returning undefined
}

public getToken()
 {

    console.log("GET TOKEN VALUE "+ localStorage.getItem('ticket'))//done for debugging, returning undefined
    return localStorage.getItem('ticket');
     }

  }
```

2 - Token Interceptor (token.interceptor.ts)

```
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import {
     HttpRequest,
     HttpHandler,
     HttpEvent,
     HttpInterceptor
     } from '@angular/common/http';
     import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';
     import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
     import { Http } from '@angular/http';

     @Injectable()
     export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
     constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService) {}
     intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
     Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

     request = request.clone({
     setHeaders: {
     Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
     }
   });

        return next.handle(request);
     }
   }
```

3 - App Component (app.component.ts)

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';
 import{Http} from '@angular/http'
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
  export class AppComponent 
  {

 constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private 
 http:HttpClient)
   {
      this.authenticationService.login();
      this.ping() ;

    }

     public ping() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost/otcs/cs.exe/api/v1/nodes/16236/output')
     .subscribe(
  data => console.log(data),
  err => console.log(err)
        );
      }
    }
```

4- App Module (app.module.ts)

```
     import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
     import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
     import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from 
     '@angular/common/http';
     import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
     import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';
     import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
     import { TokenInterceptor } from './token.interceptor';

     @NgModule({
     declarations:[AppComponent],
     imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            HttpModule
           ],

    providers: [AuthenticationService,
   {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
       multi: true
}],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
     })
        export class AppModule { }
```

On running the above project, below is the output displayed in Console:

[image]

I am unable to understand as to why is my token not getting passed with the GET Request.

Comment: Add some log statements to the code to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hi Henry, the last screenshot is from console window displaying the error. the issue is that my GET request is unable to get the authorization token. I am generating the same from a POST request successfully but on trying to attach it to the GET request, i am getting Unauthorized Error

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the token using this line

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({  ticket: data }));
```

But, your function `getToken()` is getting it wrong from `localStorage`. I think your function should look like:

```
public getToken() {
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}');
    console.log("GET TOKEN VALUE ", currentUser.ticket))//done for debugging
    return currentUser.ticket;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Castro,Its throwing an error saying "TypeError: JSON.decode is not a function"

Comment: Hi Castro, on using the above solution, I am now getting two different authentication tokens both from my put and get requests. the issue still persists

Comment: @nemishnigam you are right, it is `JSON.parse`, fix it.

Comment: @nemishnigam I don't understand what you mean by ` two different authentication tokens both from my put and get requests`, can you elaborate more?

Comment: @nemishnigam is the token included in the request's headers?

Comment: No it wasn't coming earlier. I was finally able to get it working. Thanks Castro for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

While retrieving the token in getToken, use the key as "currrentUser" instead of "ticket"

```
public getToken() {
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser) {
    return currentUser.ticket;
    } else return null;
}
```

Better to store the key in some config so its accessible everywhere hence no missing on current key.