# Why token has null value in login authentication? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

I'm trying to write login page for my website using JWT. I'm new to Angular so I'm not even sure where might be the problem. I receive null (or undefinded) value of token, even though when I print it in concole it is actuall string.

This is my UserService.ts.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { serializeNodes } from '@angular/compiler/src/i18n/digest';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  baseurl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(username, password): Observable<any>{
    //console.log(this.http.post(this.baseurl + '/api/v1/rest-auth/login/', {username, password}));
    //return this.http.post(this.baseurl + '/api/v1/rest-auth/login/', {username, password});
   return this.http.post<{token:  string}>(this.baseurl + '/api/v1/rest-auth/login/', {username, password}).pipe(
     tap(
       res => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.token));
    }))

  }
  register(email:string, password:string) {
    return this.http.post<{token: string}>(this.baseurl + '/api/v1/rest-auth/register/', {email, password}).pipe(tap(res => {
    this.login(email, password)
  }))
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  public get loggedIn(): boolean{
    return localStorage.getItem('token') !==  null;
  }

  getToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
```

I know there should be JSON.parse method in getToken, but when I used it I got this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at UserService.getToken (user.service.ts:40)
    at JwtService.intercept (jwt.service.ts:16)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1258)
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:1895)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1258)
    at HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:1945)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:1082)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:44)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:34)
```

JWTService.ts

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JwtService implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  intercept(req, next){
    let serv = this.injector.get(UserService)
    let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${serv.getToken()}` 
      }
    })
    return next.handle(tokenizedReq)
  }
}
```

Login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './../../services/user.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username = '';
  password = '';
  constructor(private api:UserService, private router: Router) { }
  StudentLogin = false;
  DeanLogin = false;
  AdminLogin = false;
  token = "";
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  showStudentLogin(){
    this.StudentLogin = true;
    this.DeanLogin = false;
    this.AdminLogin = false;
  }

  login(){
    this.api.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.token = response;
        console.log(response);
        alert(response)
        this.router.navigate(['/student'])
        console.log(this.api.loggedIn)
      },
      error =>{
        console.log("nie ok");
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }

}
```

app.modules.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/layout/header/header.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './components/layout/navigation/navigation.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { StudentComponent } from './components/student/student.component';
import { DeanComponent } from './components/dean/dean.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { JwtService } from './services/jwt.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    StudentComponent,
    DeanComponent,
    AdminComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JwtService,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I dont't even know what to look for. Alert in login.component.ts returns response as object Object.

Comment: Why is your JWT in JSON format? The token is a string. What does this mean _"I know there should be JSON.parse method in getToken"_? Why do you do `JSON.stringify(res.token)`? Where is the call to `JSON.parse`?

Comment: At first I didn't use it, but it didn/t work so after reading answers like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821886/authorization-token-getting-sent-as-null-in-the-response-in-angular I added it in my code. But with our without JSON.stringify still doesn't work

Comment: The question is unclear for me. In which line you get unexpected behavior? What is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: After getting response from UserService in login component console.log(response) gives me long string, but alert(response) results in 'object Object'. Also when I examine page in Opera in localStorage token has value undefined, same in headers: Authorization: `Bearer undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Mistake was in login function in UserService. This line should look like this:
`localStorage.setItem('token', res.key);`

I will leave it here in case someone has the same problem.